# How i can use a orderBy passing a column of the relationship in Lucid Models?

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I have two tables: `BookUnit` and `ClassBookHistoric`.

How i can order by this query by the value of the column `book_unit.unit`?

I try something like:

```
const queryClasseLivroHistorico = ClasseLivroHistorico
      .query()
      .where('class_id', request.params.class_id)
      .where('book_id', request.params.book_id)
      .with('user')
      .with('book_unit')
      .orderBy('book_unit.unit','book_unit_sequence', 'desc')
```

There's a way to do this using Lucid Models?

I'm receiving this error:

```
select * from "class_book_historics" where "class_id" = $1 and "book_id" = $2 order by "book_unit"."unit" asc limit $3 - missing FROM-clause entry for table "book_unit
```

In `ClassBookHistoric` i define this relationship:

```
class ClassBookHistoric extends Model {

    static get table () {
        return 'class_book_historics'
    }

    book_unit () {
        return this.belongsTo('App/Models/BookUnit')
    }

    user () {
        return this.belongsTo('App/Models/User')
            .select('id', 'username')
    }

}
```

**@Edit: class_book_historic_schema:**

```
class ClassBookHistoricSchema extends Schema {
  up () {
    this.create('class_book_historics', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.integer('class_id').references('id').inTable('class').notNullable()
      table.integer('book_unit_id').references('id').inTable('book_unit').notNullable()
      table.integer('book_id').references('id').inTable('books').notNullable()
      table.date('start_date')
      table.date('end_date')
      table.integer('book_unit_sequence')
      table.boolean('status').defaultTo(false)
      table.integer('user_id').references('id').inTable('users')
      table.unique(['class_id', 'book_unit_id'])
      table.timestamps()
    })
  }

  down () {
    this.drop('class_book_historics')
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your migrations files

Comment: @CrBast please see my edit

Comment: I saw that the issue has been resolved on forum.adonisjs.com. Can you post the answer and close the question?